# Mode in an array

Tags: javascript, mode

I am trying to write a code to find a mode in an array. Below is my logic. How do I improve it and is it correct?

```
var list = [2, 3, 6, 10, 10, 3];
var mode = function(values) {
  function compare(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  };

  values.sort(compare);

  for (i = 0, j = 1; i < list.length, j < list.length + 1; i++, j++) {
    if (list[i] == list[j]) {
      console.log(" Its a Mode");
    }
    else {
      console.log("not a mode");
    }
  }
}

mode(list);
```

What will be the scenario if the value of `i` and `j` will reach the end of the array?

Comment: This may be an ideal post for CodeReview on StackExchange and here is one similar example - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/68315/61815. Your core function works but you may want to handle error/exception.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a couple things.  First off, your logic doesn't actually produce the mode of the list, just any number that is repeated in the list.  If you had : `[1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6]` then 3, 4, and 5 would all report being a mode, even though in this case 3 is the actual mode.  Also, you don't actually return anything or accumulate anything, you're just logging statements to the console that don't even tell you what number you found (so not even useful in debugging).

Second, the loop is incorrect.  The conditional to end the loop can't be joined with a comma as you've done, the whole statement has to evaluate into one true or false result.

Smaller points, your loop variables aren't properly declared, which will lead to behavior you don't want if you plan on using them elsewhere.

If I were to really be trying to find the mode, I'd probably construct an object where the keys are the list values, and the value is the count of occurrences.  Then you can take the one(s) that have the highest occurrence as the mode.

The object using your list would be something like

```
{"2" : 1, "3": 2, "6": 1, "10" : 2}
```

Which is multimodal, with 3 and 10.

Comment: The `for` loop is not syntactically incorrect, in fact the initialization and the final expression will work as expected, but not the condition, due to the comma operator.

Comment: So, it *is* syntactically incorrect, b/c the condition is syntactically incorrect. I'll amend for clarity.

Comment: No, it is not syntactically incorrect. It is only semantically incorrect.